# How to display only the data from a detail component using nested routes in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am in trouble using nested routes in react router v6.

What I have is a component called pizzas where I show a list of pizzas and then when I click in one pizza I want the details to appear. All works fine except that the pizzas details appear in the same component where the list of pizzas are. I what that pizza details to appear without the list.

Little example code:

**routes.js**

```
import Sidebar from "./components/Layout/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Pizzas from "./screens/Pizzas/pizzasScreen";
import PizzaDetails from "./screens/PizzaDetails/pizzaDetails";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Sidebar />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/pizzas",
        element: <Pizzas/>,
        children: [
          { path: ":id", 
            element: <PizzaDetails /> 
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
export default routes;
```

**pizzasScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Pizzas = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Example of pizzas</p>
      <Link to="/pizzas/1">
        <span>Pizza 1</span>
      </Link>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Pizzas;
```

**pizzaDetails.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const PizzaDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{`Pizza ${id} details`}</h2>
    </>
  );
};
export default PizzaDetails;
```

With all that code what I have is the pizza screen where the list appear, well in that case only one:

[image: Pizza where I can click on to see the detail]

And then when I click on Pizza 1 I have this:

[image]

The thing is, what can I do so pizzasScreen component only renders:

Example of pizzas

Pizza 1

and pizzaDetails only renders:

Pizza 1 details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly that you ***don't*** want the `Pizzas` component to be a layout component and render the `<p>Example of pizzas</p>` element and links ***and*** the routes, then you can abstract the `<p>Example of pizzas</p>` element and links into a new component and render that as an index route for `"/pizzas"`. Effectively you move the `Outlet` up to be the layout component and move `Pizzas` component down into an index route to be rendered into the `Outlet` when the path is exactly `"/pizzas"`.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Sidebar />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/pizzas",
        element: <Outlet />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Pizzas/>,
          },
          { path: ":id", 
            element: <PizzaDetails /> 
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Pizzas

```
const Pizzas = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Example of pizzas</p>
      <Link to="/pizzas/1">
        <span>Pizza 1</span>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, where did you learn about the "index: true" feature?  I've been looking at react-router-dom documentation and the useRoutes / Object-based Routes has very little information out there.

Comment: [1] @afletcher That's a good question... I guess I just sort of got in the habit of digging in the source code to see how stuff works. Starting from the official docs for [useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes) which takes a `routes` config object like above (*the `Routes` component uses `useRoutes` under the hood*). `routes` is a `RouteObject[]` type. The [`Routes` and `Route`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) show the `RouteProps` type,

Comment: [2] @afletcher or you can look here at [source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L807-L817). The gist is that it's *just* the `Route` component props, so anything a `Route` component consumes as props is valid in the `routes` config, including an `index` prop.